# Issue copying filenames into a new folder in R

Tags: r

I am trying to copy files with a specific name structure into a new folder using R. I have used the list.files function to get get a list of the filenames. When I attempt to file.copy I only end up with around 600 files in the new folder whereas the object returned by list.files has over 1000 elements. Could someone give me a tip on how to go about troubleshooting this?

````
list.of.files<-list.files("E:\\GSCustomers\\Commercial - Active",recursive=TRUE,ignore.case=FALSE,
full.names=TRUE,pattern="[Bb]+[0-9]+[0-9]*.pdf")


file.copy(list.of.files,"D:\\Contracts\\Test 2" )```
````

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code

Comment: You could `list.of.files.target <- list.files("D:\\Contracts\\Test 2")` and do `setdiff(list.of.files, list.of.files.target)` in order to see what's missing.

Comment: My guess is there are probably indeed 600 objects in your directory, but `recursive=TRUE` counts the folders and their contents as well. If your folder had 1 subfolder containing 1 file, `list.of.files` would contain 2 elements, but your resulting directory would contain only 1 folder (which contains 1 file).